# nullpoint exception. Java. ATM

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am working on an ATM system in java.
And I keep getting NullPointerException error when I execute this code :

Why am I getting this? 
The only way for the function to work is, if I create a new user with the admin user. But when I log in without creating new user ( two user are initialised at the start of the program) and try to delete users, the console throws the NullPointerException error.

```
    public void showDeleteUser() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    System.out.println("Username of user to delete");
    input.nextLine(); 



    String userToDelete = input.nextLine();

    User _userToDelete = null;
    for (User user : users) {
        if (userToDelete.equals(user.getName())) {
            _userToDelete = user;
        }
    }

    if (_userToDelete != null) {
        users.remove(_userToDelete);
        System.out.println("Following user is deleted: " + userToDelete);
    } else {
        System.out.println("User: " + userToDelete
                + "User could not be found would you like to try again?");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, well if it depends on the user logged in, then I don't think the error is in the Java code.

Comment: can you show the error?  It will tell you where the null pointer exception is, then you can trace it and see where the problem lies

Comment: its input.nextLine(); which gives the error

Answer (score 0):

It could be because `input.nextLine();` is never assigned to a variable and thus returns a NullPointer.

You could try: `String delete = nextLine();` if you really need it. Because the next line is quite the same `String userToDelete = nextLine();` if it is so, then just remove the above mentioned line.